# OTL - how can I control the type of numerical values from SELECT

Tags: oracle-call-interface, openvms, occi, otl

In a   C++ / Oracle OTL application I have

```
 SELECT MYINT FROM MYTABLE
```

This is the basis for otl_stream selstream
On this line I get an conversion exception on an obscure platform (works well on other plafrom)
    selstream >> myint;
The exception must be related to the type of MYINT on the OTL side.

How can I control this in OTL?
I think I should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT INT( MYINT)
```

but the SQL fails.

or something like:

```
SELECT myint #:<int> FROM MYTABL
```

(Have tried different forms, still exception, while working on other platforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MYINT :#1<int>
```

Solved a similar problem for me